# waitpid() hanging when foreground child process stopped SIGTSTP

Tags: c, unix, signals, wait, child-process

I'm implementing a simple shell where a child process, with it's own PGID, is given terminal control.

Problem is, when I stop the child process with SIGTSTP (ctrl + z), the terminal just hangs and gets stuck in waitpid:

[image]

How do I get waitpid to stop hanging?

```
void wait_job() {

  int status;
  int corpse;

  int wait_flags = WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED;

  while ((corpse = waitpid(-1, &status, wait_flags)) > 0) {
    if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
      printf("child stopped, sign num = %d, corpse = %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status), corpse);      
    }
    else if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
      printf("child exited, sign num = %d, corpse = %d\n", status, corpse);
    }
    else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
      printf("child continued, sign num = %d, corpse = %d\n", status, corpse);
    }
  }
}

int main() {

    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTTIN, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);

    char buffer[100];
    char prompt[] = "Press enter: ";

    while (1) {

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, prompt, sizeof(prompt) - 1);

        int n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 10);
        buffer[n - 1] = '\0';

        int pid;

        if ((pid = fork()) == 0) { // Child
            signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
            signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL);
            signal(SIGTTIN, SIG_DFL);
            signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_DFL);

            setpgid(pid, pid);
            tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, pid);

            char* argv[] = { "sleep", "5", NULL };
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
            exit(0);
        }

        // Parent
        setpgid(pid, pid);
        tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, pid);

        wait_job();
        tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, getpgid(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly you're asking. If you don't want to wait until a process completes, just don't call a function that's specifically designed to wait until a process completes. Instead, do whatever it is that you want to do instead.

Comment: I'd like to suspend the sleep 5 and move it to the background by regaining control of the terminal

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Implementing-a-Shell.html). There's lots of documentation on how to implement a shell and how to do job control.